# Circular QGraphicsView

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I'm constructing a GUI in PyQt with a QGraphicsView that will display a large network of interconnected items, and I want the ability to superimpose a smaller portal that shows a distant part of the network - sort of a "picture in picture" kind of thing. This alone isn't an issue, as I could just add a second QGraphicsView and set it to show a different part of the same scene.

The trick is, I want the inset view to be circular. Does anybody know how to change the shape of a QGraphicsView to something other than a rectangle, either by subclassing or by some other trick? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the `setMask` function and pass it a `QRegion`:

Example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QWidget()
    w.resize(430, 460)
    lay = QVBoxLayout(w)
    view = QGraphicsView()
    view.resize(400, 400)
    region = QRegion(view.rect(), QRegion.Ellipse)
    view.setMask(region)
    lay.addWidget(view)
    btn = QPushButton(w)
    lay.addWidget(btn)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make the circle smooth?